# WDIO Automation. Spec symbols are missed in set text after update chrome browser

Tags: macos, google-chrome, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

After update chrome browser to the Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)
spec symbols are missed in set text and browser settings page is opening unexpectedly on enter spec symbol or capital letter.

Tests are based on WDIO http://webdriver.io/

For example if I execute

```
browser.setValue(selector,"Text #1");
```

the result in the input will be: "Text 1" and 2 opening of settings Page

Affected MAC OS only, no issue on Windows OS

Please advise how to fix, thanks for sharing any experience.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug that you should post into the github section of webdriver.io

Please check if you use the latest version of your webdriver & selenium.

However you can maybe use http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/keys.html

to enter keys you currently can´t use.

Comment: Opened here: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/2387 and here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2113, updated the chromedriver to the latest version 2.33 - issue is still present

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in chromedriver
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2113
Fixed after update chromedriver to 2.33 version and update chrome browser to 62.0.3202.94 version